# unrecognized or unsupported array type in openCV

Tags: c#, opencv

I am working on project which i get a stream of video from camera and make a processing on each frame in this video.

I am using openCv and c# and the problem is:
I made a `Capture _capture;` and initiated it and assigned an event to it with `_capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;`
and i used the following code in "ProcessFrame"

```
using(Image<Bgr, Byte> image = _capture.RetrieveBgrFrame())
{
  if(image != null)
  {
    image.SmoothGaussian(3);
    frameQueue.Enqueue(image);
    captureImgBox.Image=image;
  }
}
```

where frameQueue is `Queueu<Image<Bgr, Byte>>` used to save all frames and work on them in backgrounWorker.

First frame is running without any error, but the second is not.

The exception is:
OpenCV: unrecognized or unsupported array type in this line
`captureImgBox.Image=image;`

Comment: In this line `captureImgBox.Image=image` are you trying to assign a UI value? This might not be possible because this method does not run in UI thread. I know the error message does not say something like this but you might want to check innerexceptions.

Comment: InnerException result is null
and Source is Systems.Windows.Forms

So i can`t get any other information about this exception.